# Itunes Connect rejected

Tags: xcode, ios7, app-store-connect

I had my app rejected, now I am ready to upload the new version but I the rejected version is still as rejected in the iTunes Connect page. I can set the app new version for Testflight but not for iTunes review.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because StackOverflow is not Apple iTunes support.

Comment: Thank you for your comments Mr. Darin Dimitrov, but this is related to Xcode and application upload. Am I wrong?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about apple review processes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is the reason you can not upload your new version, you have to delete the old one. In your iTunes connect web page:

1. Login in iTunesConnect web page
2. Select App Store
3. Select the last version below Pricing and Availability
4. Scroll down to Build, it is below Apple Watch
5. There should be your rejected version.
6. There is a (-) minus red signal click on it (it will delete the version rejected)
7. Upload your new version 
   Remember: you have so select a new version Apple will not accept the binary as version 1 or whatever is your rejected version. Have to change in the info page on your app. 
   Let me know if you can not follow it... and good luck.

Comment: That is what I was missing thank you very much, I don't know if I can give the answer as accept, because another user wants to delete the question.